# asp.net mvc 3 entity framework, passing model info in Get request of create action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm having trouble passing view information from my Get/Create action to my view. Here are my three model classes;

```
public class Competition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompetitionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Prize { get; set; }
}

public class CompetitionEntry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CompetitionEntryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int CompetitionId { get; set; }
}

public class CompetitionEntryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Competition Competitions { get; set; }
    public int CompetitionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is my Get/Create action in CompetitionEntry Controller;

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    CompetitionEntryViewModel competitionentryviewmodel = db.CompetitionEntriesView.Find(id);
    return View(competitionentryviewmodel);
}
```

I know this doesn't work. The id parameter goes into the URL fine. How to I get access to my Competition class in th Get action? I need to be able to show the competion name on my Create Competition entry view.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't have expected a ViewModel class to be retrieved from the db context, but put together from entities that are retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new to all this, but I'll edit my project and my question in a moment

Comment: I think the comment I left under the below ansewer explains my intention better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
      var data = db.CompetitionEntriesView.Find(id);

      CompetitionEntryViewModel competitionentryviewmodel = new CompetitionEntryViewModel();
      competitionentryviewmodel.CompetitionName = data.Name;

      return View(competitionentryviewmodel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you mean ViewBag? Viewstate is giving an error,'Cannot be resolved'.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes indeed. ViewState, ViewData, ViewBag....it gets confusing sometimes.

Comment: Indeed it does! I tried this but what I'm trying to do is get the name of the competition through the navigation property public Competition Competitions in my CompetitionEntryViewmodel so  I can write @Model.Competition.Name in my Create View. But I get an 'Object not set to..' error. I need to pass the Competition.Name propert into the view through my Get/Create action, I just don't know how.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect the solution you need. Or at least to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and mark as answer if it sets me down the right track, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is build an object graph and display it through a view model. In order to do this, you need to map your domain model(s) to your view model.

You can do the mapping yourself by writing a lot of code (re-inventing the wheel), or, you could consider using third party tools to do this for you. I recommend you use an AutoMapper as it is very simple to use imo.

The other problem is that your view model contains a domain model. This is likely to cause you a lot of headache in near future. If I were you, I would replace Competition with CompetitionViewModel.

I would also consider creating a view model for a list of competitions, i.e. CompetitionsViewModel. Look into partial views to see how you can display a list of competitions.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll look into automapper.